# "Error during CMS conversion: Could not open scanner ICM profile"

Tags: scanner, sane, color-management

I'm using `xsane` to scan images with my Brother MFC-L2710DW multifunction. Scanning works fine, but - I repeatedly get an error message saying:

> Error during CMS conversion: Ccould not open scanner ICM profile

I've tried switching the colorspace choice between the options: "Embed Scanner ICM profile", "Convert to sRGB" and "Convert to working color space" - but I still get the error message.

My questions:

- Why does xsane need the "ICM profile" if it can scan without it?
- How can I tell xsane to stop looking for that profile?
- How can I provide xsane with the correct profile?

Answer (score 5):

A partial answer:

Color management, or application of a color profile, is an optional action when scanning a document. `xsane` is complaining about not being able to perform it since it's enabled by a preference - and the preference is set by default. Of course it's problematic to default to expecting a file that's not guaranteed to be present, but that's how it is.

Anyway, in xsane's initial scanning dialog, on the menus, localte <kbd>Preferences</kbd> | <kbd>Enable Color Management</kbd> and disable it.

[image]

You should now stop getting error messages.